# check on pandas dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have a pandas dataframe composed by 3 columns.

```
  index  start  end     value
    0       0   37647   0
    1   37648   37846   1
    2   37847   42874   0
    3   42875   43049   1
    4   43050   51352   0
    5   51353   51665   -1
    6   51666   54500   0
    7   54501   54501   -1
    8   54502   55259   0
```

I would like to implement a check on the difference between start and end of each row.
In particular what I would like to do is:

```
if end row x - start row x  == 0 incorporate this row in the previous row
```

For example the 8th row

```
7   54501   54501   -1
```

has end - start = 0. I would like to modify the dataframe like this

```
  index  start  end     value
    0       0   37647   0
    1   37648   37846   1
    2   37847   42874   0
    3   42875   43049   1
    4   43050   51352   0
    5   51353   51665   -1
    6   51666   54501   0
    7   54502   55259   0
```

and then since the 7th and the 8th row now have the same "value" it should become

```
    0       0   37647   0
    1   37648   37846   1
    2   37847   42874   0
    3   42875   43049   1
    4   43050   51352   0
    5   51353   51665   -1
    6   51666   55259   0
```

**EDITED**

Please note that a particular case would be

```
  index  start  end     value
    0       0   37647   0
    1   37648   37846   1
    2   37847   42874   0
    3   42875   43049   1
    4   43050   51352   0
    5   51353   51665   -1
    6   51666   54500   0
    7   54501   54501   -1
    8   54502   54502   0
    9   54503   55259   1
```

In this case there are 2 consecutive rows (8th and 9th) for which the difference between end and start values is 0.
In this case the answer proposed gives an error since the index 7th was deleted previously.
I solved this case using a while loop instead of a for loop, but I guess it is not the best thing to do.

For this case we should have

```
  index  start  end     value
    0       0   37647   0
    1   37648   37846   1
    2   37847   42874   0
    3   42875   43049   1
    4   43050   51352   0
    5   51353   51665   -1
    6   51666   54502   0
    7   54503   55259   1
```

Answer (score 0):

Using numpy `where` you can do it like this:

```
import numpy as np

inp = np.where(df.start == df.end)[0]
droplist = []
save = 0
j = 0
for i in range(len(inp)):
    if inp[i] > 0:
        if inp[i]-inp[i-1] == 1:
            j += 1
            save += 1
            df.loc[inp[i]-1-j,"end"] += save
        else:
            j = 0
            save = 0
            df.loc[inp[i]-1,"end"] += 1
        droplist.append(inp[i])
df = df.drop(droplist).reset_index(drop=True)

droplist = []
jnp = np.where(df.value == df.value.shift(-1))[0]
for jj in jnp:
    df.loc[jj,"end"] = df.loc[jj+1,"end"]
    droplist.append(jj+1)
df = df.drop(droplist).reset_index(drop=True)
```

There might be a more pythonic way without for-loops using numpy though.

EDIT: Fixed for consecutive rows.

Comment: Thanks for your solution, but if there are 2 consecutive rows (indices) for which the difference between end and start values is 1 there will be an error because the code won't find the index previously dropped..

Comment: @gabboshow - can you update your question to reflect that situation so that we can better answer it?

Comment: Hi Khris thanks! would be nice that if ii == 0 then the first row is merged to the second if the second if the second is OK (ie difference !=0) if also the second has 0 as difference between start and end then first and second row should be merged to the 3rd and so on..

Comment: I ve added this to your code:
            if ii > 0:
                AltitudeChange.loc[ii-1,"End"] += 1
                droplist.append(ii)
            else:
                AltitudeChange.loc[ii+1,"Start"] -= 1
                droplist.append(ii)

what do you think?

Comment: I'm sorry, the change I made did not solve the problem, I will work on it. Does the method in the other answer not work?

Comment: I fixed my code again but now it has become really ugly and bulky, I'm not happy with it. About your added code, looks fine to me, does it work?

Comment: the code in the other answer returns warning and I am not confident with them. The code I have added seems to do the job..

Comment: ps what was the problem with the previous version of your code?

Answer (score 0):

This could probably be cleaned up a bit, but should work.

Code:

```
# FIRST CHECK
df['end'][df['end'].shift(-1) == df['start'].shift(-1)] = df['end'].shift(-1)
df.drop_duplicates('end', inplace = True)

# SECOND CHECK
df['end'][df['value'].shift(-1) == df['value']] = df['end'].shift(-1)
df['value'][df['value'].shift(-1) == df['value']] = (df['value'] + df['value'].shift(-1)).fillna(0).astype(int)
df.drop_duplicates('end', inplace = True)
```

Output:

```
   start    end  value
0      0  37647      0
1  37648  37846      1
2  37847  42874      0
3  42875  43049      1
4  43050  51352      0
5  51353  51665     -1
6  51666  55259      0
```

Comment: To not get the SettingWithCopyWarning you should use the `loc`/`iloc`-syntax everywhere you assign values to rows or a subset of the dataframe, e.g. when you assign to a subset from a boolean filter like you do.

Comment: Thanks @Khris.  Updated answer to not throw warning and reduced lines.