# Pandas - merging rows with contiguous intervals

Tags: python, pandas

I've started using Pandas recently and have been stumbling over this issue for a few days. I have a dataframe with interval information that looks a bit like this:

```
    df = pd.DataFrame({'RangeBegin' : [1,3,5,10,12,42,65],
               'RangeEnd' : [2,4,7,11,41,54,100],
               'Var1' : ['A','A','A','B','B','B','A'],
               'Var2' : ['A','A','B','B','B','B','A']})

     RangeBegin  RangeEnd Var1 Var2
0           1         2    A    A
1           3         4    A    A
2           5         7    A    B
3          10        11    B    B
4          12        41    B    B
5          42        54    B    B
6          65       100    A    A
```

It is sorted by RangeBegin. The idea is to to end up with something like this instead:

```
       RangeBegin  RangeEnd Var1 Var2
0         1.0       4.0    A    A
2         5.0       7.0    A    B
3        10.0      54.0    B    B
6        65.0     100.0    A    A
```

Where every "duplicate" (matching Var1 and Var2) row with contiguous ranges is aggregated into a single row. I'm thinking of expanding this algorithm to detect and deal with overlaps, but I'd like to get this working properly first.

You see, I've got a solution working by using iterrows to build a new dataframe row-by-row, but it takes far too long on my real dataset and I'd like to use a more vectorized implementation. 
I've looked into groupby but can't find a set of keys (or a function to apply to said groups) that would make this work.

Here's my current implementation as it stands:

```
def test():
    df = pd.DataFrame({'RangeBegin' : [1,3,5,10,12,42,65],
                   'RangeEnd' : [2,4,7,11,41,54,100],
                   'Var1' : ['A','A','A','B','B','B','A'],
                   'Var2' : ['A','A','B','B','B','B','A']})
    print(df)

    i = 0
    cols = df.columns
    aggData = pd.DataFrame(columns = cols)
    for row in df.iterrows():
        rowIndex, rowData = row
        #if our new dataframe is empty or its last row is not contiguous, append it
        if(aggData.empty or not duplicateContiguousRow(cols,rowData,aggData.loc[i])):
            aggData = aggData.append(rowData)
            i=rowIndex
        #otherwise, modify the last row
        else:
            aggData.loc[i,'RangeEnd'] = rowData['RangeEnd']
    print(aggData)

def duplicateContiguousRow(cols, row, aggDataRow):
    #first bool: are the ranges contiguous?
    contiguousBool = aggDataRow['RangeEnd']+1 == row['RangeBegin']
    if(not contiguousBool):
        return False

    #second bool: is this row a duplicate (minus range columns)?
    duplicateBool = True
    for col in cols:
        if(not duplicateBool):
            break
        elif col not in ['RangeBegin','RangeEnd']:
            #Nan != Nan
            duplicateBool = duplicateBool and (row[col] == aggDataRow[col] or (row[col]!=row[col] and aggDataRow[col]!=aggDataRow[col]))
    return duplicateBool
```

---

**EDIT:** [This question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42763060/check-on-pandas-dataframe) just got asked while I was writing this one. The answer looks promising

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can use `groupby` for this purpose, when first detecting the [consecutive segments](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14358567/finding-consecutive-segments-in-a-pandas-data-frame):

```
df['block'] = ((df['Var1'].shift(1) != df['Var1']) | (df['Var2'].shift(1) != df['Var2'])).astype(int).cumsum()
df.groupby(['Var1', 'Var2', 'block']).agg({'RangeBegin': np.min, 'RangeEnd': np.max}).reset_index()
```

will result in:

```
  Var1 Var2  block  RangeBegin  RangeEnd
0    A    A      1           1         4
1    A    A      4          65       100
2    A    B      2           5         7
3    B    B      3          10        54
```

You could then sort by `block` to restore the original order.

Comment: Great answer, thanks! Just one question, is there any reason you group by Var1 and Var2 as well as block? I appear to get the same results grouping by block alone

Comment: Oh no, it will remove those columns from the output then, if you do not apply a function to them aswell.

Comment: Excellent answer, would upvote twice if possible. Couldn't for the life of me find a way to detect the consecutive blocks